# Skype4COM: to identify the incoming call event and assosciate it with one of the active skype clients on my machine

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com, skype4java

**My Project:**
I need to build up a Skype Listener server for one of my project. It will:
 1. Host 8 different dummy Skype accounts.
 2. All accounts will already have associated:
  (a) Already Recorded audio files 
  (b) Pre-recorded video files .
3. A Skype call to any of these Skype accounts will automatically initiate the pre-recorded audio or the video depending upon the call type.

**My Reasearch:**
 I have researched in Skype Developer forum but I could not find any URI or API to accept the incoming programatically. However I am able to catch the Incoming call event and respond to that using Skype4COM.

http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API/Event-for-incoming-call/td-p/9174

Now As I have to implement the same in 8 differenet skype account running on same machine using secondary method provided by SKype. But while using the same, I am unable to identify that when an incoming call event occurs, which is the account which is receiving the call. So whicheve be the account it opens the same pre-recorded video and not the one assosciated with the skype account.
Hope I am clear in explaining it.

**My Problem**:
1.I am looking for a method (using SkypeKIT or Skype4COM) to identify the incoming call event and assosciate it with one of the active skype clients on my machine.
2. To play the pre-recorded video and audio, I am currently changing the viedo source of the skype client on my machine. Now Since all the Skype accounts are running on the same client so I am unable to attach different video sources to different accounts. Is there a way to run multiple skype instance on same machine?
Any suggestion/immediate help on how to accomplish these using SkypeKIT and SKype4COM or any other way will be highly appreciated.

P.S: I have re-posted this question with adding my research work.

Regards
Raj

Comment: Is there a way to run multiple skype instance on same machine?  <-- just use virtual machines to be on the safe side

Comment: Hi Mikko Thanks for the advise. Ia m going ahead with VMs to solve the multi skype issue.  Any help regarding playing pre-recorded audio after receiving a skype call. Also could not find any code regarding the playing voice mail greeting else i could utilise that also to develope the code. HELP needed urgently

Comment: Here is related Skype4Py issue: https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/issues/15 looks like no luck for somebody. For urgent help I suggest you simply hire external consultants who have worked with Skype APIs before, as people answering on the forums really don't care if your need answers now or after one year.